# Pause setInterval on hover of Ajax Quick Cart and resume when not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set up my Ajax Quick Cart so that if the user is hovering over the quick cart (in other words interacting with it) it delays a setInterval that I have set on it to close the cart once something has been added after 3 seconds.

I'm not that great with JS so any help would be appreciated!

This is my original code:

```
{% comment %}
Ajaxify your cart with this plugin.
Documentation:
    - http://shopify.com/timber#ajax-cart
{% endcomment %}
{% if settings.ajax_cart_enable %}
  {{ 'handlebars.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% include 'ajax-cart-template' %}
  {{ 'ajax-cart.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      ajaxCart.init({
        formSelector: '#AddToCartForm',
        cartContainer: '#CartContainer',
        addToCartSelector: '#AddToCart',
        cartCountSelector: '#CartCount',
        cartCostSelector: '#CartCost',
        moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }}
      });
    });

    jQuery('body').on('ajaxCart.afterCartLoad', function(evt, cart) {
      // Bind to 'ajaxCart.afterCartLoad' to run any javascript after the cart has loaded in the DOM

      timber.RightDrawer.open();
    });

    jQuery('body').on('click','#AddToCart', function(evt, cart) {

          timber.RightDrawer.open();

              var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
              timber.RightDrawer.close();
              clearInterval(myVar);
              }, 3000);
    });
```

This is part of the original code I have tried to adapt to try to get it to work but still no luck, it just breaks my setInterval:

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#AddToCart', function(evt, cart) {

          timber.RightDrawer.open();

              $('#CartContainer').hover(function(ev){
                  clearInterval(myVar);
              }, function(ev){
                  myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
                  timber.RightDrawer.close();
                  clearInterval(myVar);
                  }, 3000);
              });
        });
```

Comment: Not the answer: BUT You want to use mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: Check here for a good solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913703/adding-pause-on-hover-to-setinterval

Comment: I've updated my question with what I just tried after looking at your example but can't seem to get it to work without it breaking my setInterval. Any suggestions?

Comment: you shouldn't stop and restart the timer that way, as sometimes the browser will lose the event related to the mouse entering or leaving the area. You'd much better incorporate the code testing if the mouse is hovering or not inside the routine for the timer itself and let it fire again and again until definitely not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good approach, and as others have commented, there are some potential caveats with doing things the way you are doing them.

But, to answer the question, the JavaScript below appears to work as described.  It looks like your main issue was the fact that you were not setting the time interval after clicking the button; it was only being set after clicking the button AND after hovering and un-hovering the container.

Below, I have moved the delayed clearing to its own function (`doDelayedClear()`) to prevent duplicate code, and I call `doDelayedClear()` both when the button is clicked and when the mouse has hovered and un-hovered.

I have also added some calls to `console.log()` so that you can watch what is happening.

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/nb9tetLs/

**JavaScript**:

```
var myVar = null;

jQuery('body').on('click', '#AddToCart', function (evt, cart) {
    timber.RightDrawer.open();
    doDelayedClear();
    jQuery('#CartContainer').hover(function (ev) {
        console.log('hovering...');
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }, function (ev) {
        console.log('not hovering...');
        doDelayedClear();
    });
});

function doDelayedClear() {
    myVar = setInterval(function () {
        timber.RightDrawer.close();
        console.log('Set interval executed!');
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I've tried what you have suggested but have found that although this works for adding the item to the cart it then breaks the other cart button that was just opening and closing on click. Now that button also responds to the timer. I apologise as I'm not great with JS so finding it a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: Please post some of the HTML so that we know what we're dealing with. There should only be one button with ID AddToCart, so if this code interferes with a different button, something is wrong with the HTML.

Comment: Its hard for me to show my HTML as I'm building a Shopify store and its all in segments but I've used the Shopify Timber framework - http://timber-demo.myshopify.com - so you can see what I'm working from..